# selenium webdriver input field to focus in ruby for firefox

Tags: ruby, selenium, focus, webdriver, input-field

I am currently using selenium webdriver 2.35 for firefox being programmed in ruby. I am having an issue where I can not get the webdriver to focus correctly on an input field element. By default, there is some gray text already populated in the field. When a user clicks on this field, that gray text is supposed to disappear and allow the user type into field.

Using the webdriver, I would send the click command to that element and it would click, but nothing would visually happen. I also checked to see the active element and in fact it is that field(after clicking on the element). (I used this to check: `driver.switch_to.active_element`)

Also, I would send keys to that field and it will show up gray either appended to the default text or by clearing that field and sending those keys

Methods that I used but did not work

1) `driver.find_element(element).click`

2) `driver.action.move_to.element.click.perform`

Does anyone have any suggestions? (I know that this may sound ambiguous but feel free to question me need any more information)

I am not sure if this helps or not but here is the html from before the click(also the same result after using the click function in selenium

This is the html before the click (and the result after using the selenium click function

```
<html>
    <td id="ext-gen273" class="x-toolbar-cell input-container">
        <div id="ext-gen274" class="x-form-field-wrap x-form-field-trigger-wrap" style="width: 467px;">
            <input id="ext-comp-1024" class="x-form-text x-form-field autofoo-search-txtbx foo-search-dropdown x-form-empty-field" type="text" name="ext-comp-1024" autocomplete="off" size="24" style="width: 398px;"></input>
        </div>
    </td>
</html>
```

This html appears after  is after the user manually clicks on the field.

```
<html>
    <td id="ext-gen273" class="x-toolbar-cell input-container">
        <div id="ext-gen274" class="x-form-field-wrap x-form-field-trigger-wrap x-trigger-wrap-focus" style="width: 467px;">
            <input id="ext-comp-1024" class="x-form-text x-form-field autofoo-search-txtbx foo-search-dropdown x-form-focus" type="text" name="ext-comp-1024" autocomplete="off" size="24" style="width: 398px;"></input>
        </div>
    </td>
</html>
```

I also noticed that after the user manually clicks on the field, the selenium commands work correctly

Comment: Do you want highlight to the element before click?

Comment: Is this grey text being put in there via the `value` attr? and javascript does stuff with it?  If not, then it's just a `placeholder` attr and you can just call `send_keys` on it.

Comment: put your html in the post itself,not in the comment..please

Comment: Yes.. what @ArupRakshit said. that's very difficult to read

Comment: @Arup Rakshit sorry about that hope this is better

Comment: @sircapsalot sorry about that

Comment: im having the same problem, i've been using send_keys which was working on chrome at least and i thought worked on firefox